# How to find fakeroot package to lauch jpackage

Tags: java, jpackage, fakeroot

I've created a .jar with eclipse on ubuntu, java14 and javafx.
I wanted to create an application with **jpackage**.
So, I typed in a terminal jpackage --name Test --input . --main-jar Test.jar.

I have had the response :
**Bundler DEB Bundle skipped because of a configuration problem:
Can not find fakeroot. Reason: Cannot run program "fakeroot":
error=2, No such file or directory**

But, the command sudo apt install fakeroot gives nothing.

So, how is it possible to get fakeroot package or to use successfully jpackage ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I tried with apt-get and it worked:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fakeroot
```